# $H^0(X,\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{F}(X)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ a topological space and $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf. I have to prove that $H^0(X,\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{F}(X)$.

I have the cochain $0\rightarrow \mathcal{F}_0(X)\rightarrow \mathcal{F}_1(X)\rightarrow...$, with $\mathcal{F}_0=\bar{\mathcal{F}}$, $\mathcal{F}_1=\bar{\mathcal{F}_1^{'}}$ where $\mathcal{F_1^{'}}=\bar{\mathcal{F}}/\mathcal{F} $.

$\bar{\mathcal{F}}(U) =\prod_{x\in U} \mathcal{F}_x$

$H^0(X,\mathcal{F}):= Ker(\mathcal{F}_0(X)\rightarrow \mathcal{F_1}(X))$

Now I consider the projection  $\pi:\bar{\mathcal{F}}(X)\rightarrow\bar{\mathcal{F}}(X)/\mathcal{F}(X)$ and the inclusion  $i:\bar{\mathcal{F}}(X)/\mathcal{F}(X)\rightarrow \bar{\mathcal{F_1^{'}}}(X)$.

Therefore I obtain

$i\circ\pi$: $\mathcal{F}_0(X)\rightarrow \mathcal {F_1}(X) 
$.

$H^0(X,\mathcal{F})= Ker (i\circ \pi)= \mathcal{F}(X)$ because $i$ is injective.

It's right?

Comment: What does $\overline F$ mean ?

Comment: The approach you present is unclear and difficult to understand because you've defined very few things in your proof. You need to clarify your work if you want to make it understandable to us so we can help.

Comment: @KReiser I add  details. Thank you for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that to compute $H^k(X,F)$ you have to choose an injective resolution of F $$0\to F\overset{i}\to F_1 \overset{f_1}\to F_2 \to ...$$ and then consider the exact sequence $$F_1(X) \overset{f_1(X)}\to F_2(X)  \overset{f_2(X)}\to F_3(X) \to ...$$ Then, we have $$H^k(X,F) =\text{ker}(f_{k+1}(X))/\text{im}(f_{k}(X)).$$ So in your case, we have simply $$H^0(X,F) = \text{ker}(f_1(X)) = \text{im}(i(X))=F(X).$$

Comment: I have to know how is  $f_1$ or is a  general fact?

Comment: No, you only have to know that $f_1$ is a monomorphism and it is sufficient for the proof.

Comment: I've edited my post. No, you don't need to know explicitely the resolution. By a theoretic result, you know that it always exists. However, considering sheaves, it is usual to take flabby resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

What cohomology are you considering?
If it is the $\check{\text{C}}$ech cohomology, the situation (for cohomology groups in general degrees) is more delicate.

First of all, you need a covering of your topological space $X$. Let $\mathfrak{U} :=\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ denote such a covering. Then consider the chain complex
$$
0 \to \prod_{i\in I}\mathcal{F}(U_i) \stackrel{\partial}\to \prod_{i,j \in I}\mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j) \stackrel{\partial}{\to}\dots.
$$
In general the $k$-th group in this chain complex is defined by
$$
C^k(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F}):= \prod_{i_1,\dots,i_{k+1}\in I} \mathcal{F}(U_{i_k} \cap \dots \cap U_{i_{k+1}}),
$$
and the coboundary operator is given by
$$
\partial: C^k(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F}) \to C^{k+1}(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F}),
$$
$$
(\partial(f))_{i_1\dots i_{k+2}} = \sum_{j=1}^{k+2} (-1)^{j+1}\left. f_{i_1\dots \hat{i_j} \dots {i_{k+2}}}\right|_{U_{i_1} \cap\dots\cap \hat{U_{i_j}}\cap\dots \cap U_{i_k}}.
$$
To clarify the notation a little bit, elements of $C^k(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F})$ are sequences of elements indexed by $I^{k+1}$, so the formula above gives a certain component of such a sequence, whereas $f$ denotes the whole sequence.
The hat indicates that the index is omitted. 
The sheaf cohomology (corresponding to the cover $\mathfrak{U}$) is defined by
$$
H^k(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F}):=\frac{\ker(\partial:C^k(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F})\to C^{k+1}(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F}))}{\text{im}(\partial: C^{k-1}(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F}) \to C^k(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F})}.
$$
Note that this definition certainly does depend on the cover, and in general, one must take a direct limit which is for the moment very difficult to compute. But fortunately, this is not the case for $k =0$.

Obviously the subspace that should be quotient out in the definition is zero, so we only need to find the kernel of 
$$
\partial: C^0(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F}) \to C^1(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F}).
$$
But if $f = (f_i)_{i\in I}\in C^0(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F})$, such that 
$$
\partial(f) = 0,
$$
then 
$$
(\partial(f))_{ij} = 0
$$
for all $i,j \in I$. 
Using the definition, we find
$$
\left.f_i\right|_{U_i\cap U_j} = \left.f_j\right|_{U_i\cap U_j}.
$$
But by definition of a sheaf, we know there exists an $g\in \mathcal{F}(X)$, such that 
$$
\left.g\right|_{U_i} = f_i.
$$
So elements of 
$$
\ker(\partial:C^0(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F}) \to C^1(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F}),
$$
precisely correspond to global sections $g\in \mathcal{F}(X)$. This is true independent of the chosen cover $\mathfrak{U}$, the cohomology group
$$
H^0(X;\mathcal{F}) = \ker(\partial:C^0(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F}) \to C^1(\mathfrak{U};\mathcal{F})) \cong \mathcal{F}(X). 
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I don't know anything about Cech Cohomology.

Comment: @PregatireMatematica Could you elaborate on how $H^0(X,\mathcal{F})$ is defined then?

Comment: The construction is made with right derived functors.

Comment: @PregatireMatematica Ok I'm sorry, I can't help then, as I do not have any knowledge of derived functors.